# Binding GridView to List<Object>

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I've been scouring through the web (including stack overflow) for the solution to this problem. The current problem I'm having is that I'm binding that my data incorrectly to my View. When a user first navigates to the home page, the GridView shows nothing. When i go to another page and then come back to the home page, the list is shown except it is populated with strings that say "***MyProject.Model.MyTask***"

I know the issue isn't with my model or viewmodel as I'm able to retrieve the list properly with the data inside. One issue could be with my await call in my viewmodel. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong in binding my List to the GridView?

**ViewModel**

```
  public HomeViewModel(IDataService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)          _dataService = dataService;
     _navigationService = navigationService;
     Initialize();
  }      

  private async Task Initialize() {
     MyTasks = await ApiHandlker.GetMyTasks();
  }

  private List<MyTask> _myTasks;
  public List<MyTask> MyTasks {
     get { return _myTasks; }
     set { _myTasks = value; }
  }
```

**Model**

```
public class MyTask {
    public string TaskID { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string TaskAssigneeID { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

**View**

```
<GridView x:Name="gridViewMyTasks" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTasks}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskName}"></TextBlock>
</GridView>
```

Comment: There is a bit of redundancy in MyTask with the property naming. Also ItemsSource does not exist on GridView for me. Are you sure this is your code?

Comment: @Measuring the OP is under WinRT XAML. the WPF `GridView` is just a `View` for the `ListView`.

Comment: @HighCore Ah, pardon me then. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bind it to a list, bind instead to an `ObservableCollection<MyTask>`. You're populating the list AFTER the GridView has bound to it, so the GridView doesn't know it changed. If you're not populating it and instead simply setting it, you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Secondly, what you're essentially doing is setting the source to your list, then trying to add a `TextBlock` also as a source (and being ignored). What you're looking for instead is to set the `ItemTemplate`. Something like:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) for more information.

Comment: could you elaborate on the first paragraph, specifically populating the list after the gridview has bound to it? How would I populate the list before the gridview has bound with it?

Comment: You can't really with an async call. To do it before binding it would probably have to be done during construction. Any other time is, at best, a crapshoot. If you take an existing list and populate it later, it won't tell the `GridView` when more items are added. If you set it to a new list later that's fine as long as you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you use an `ObservableCollection<MyTask>` it's smart enough to tell the `GridView` that it received new items as you populate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` in the setter of `MyTasks`.

You may find my recent [MSDN article on asynchronous data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) helpful.

Comment: Quote: "When a user first navigates to the home page, the GridView shows nothing" - so yeah, this is probably related. I reached the same conclusion and listed it in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parts of the XAML:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridViewMyTasks" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTasks}">
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskName}"/>
       <DataTemplate>
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```